# sentence structure when talking about weather

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to say :明天晴天   or should I always use "shi" in this type of sentence "明天是晴天" ?
If both of them are right,is there any difference between them?

Comment: 明天晴天 is the correct form,  see "名词谓语句，sentence with a nominal predicate" e.g. "外国人实用汉语语法＂quoted at previous Q "Verb used to deny age"

Comment: cf.＂实用现代汉语语法＂（more complete than ＂外国人实用汉语语法＂ **名词谓语句**  名词谓语句指体词性词语作谓语的句子。体词指名词、名词短语、代词、数词、数量词短语和＂的＂子短语， **名词谓语句的主语和谓语之间没有＂是＂子**  。例如：（１）今天 _除夕_ 。（＂除夕＂是谓语）（２）A：你们都 _十几_ 了？（＂十几＂是谓语）B：哥哥 _十八_ ，我 _十二_ 。（＂十几＂是谓语，＂十二＂是谓语）（３）喂，你 _哪儿_ ？（打电话）（＂哪儿＂是谓语）一、名词谓语句的类型（一）由一个名词构成的名词谓语句。例如：（１）今天 _星期二_ 。（２）明天 _中秋节_ 。（３）刚才还 _晴天_ 呢，现在又 _阴天_ 了。在实际语言中由单个名词作谓语的名词谓语语句较少见。 三、名词谓语句的用途（一）说明时间、日期， **天气**  ，籍贯等。这类句子的谓语大多是名词、名词短语以及部分代词。谓语和主语有同一性。例如：（１）现在 _十二_ 点。（２）今天 _什么日子_ ？今天＂_五四_ ＂青年节。（５）他 _英国人_ ，我 _加拿大人_ 。（６）他 _东北口音_ ，可能是东北人。

Answer (score 2):

天晴 sunny (adj)

晴天 sunny day (n)

明天天晴 = (it will be) sunny tomorrow.

明天是個晴天 = Tomorrow is a sunny day.

If you wrote 明天晴天, it would be a noun (tomorrow) followed by another noun (sunny day). The verb 是 (is) and the classifier(個) are omitted.